# Converting DD-MM char to dates

Tags: r, date

Having a lot of trouble converting my data to date format. I'm performing analysis on weather data for a class and haven't even gotten to the analysis part. This part isn't required for the class but is bugging the hell out of me.

In general I'm trying compare weather patterns across years. The dates are formatted as `dd-mmm` in the rows, with `years` in each column.

First off, I appreciate any insight in handling weather data like this in general.

I'm trying to convert to date because it seems like good practice and for ease in plotting the temperature over time. Example code below:

```
# sample weather data
df <- data.frame("DAY" = c("1-Jul", "2-Jul", "3-Jul"),
                 "1996" = c(98,97,97),
                 "1997" = c(86,90,93))
df

# convert column to date format
dates <- as.Date(df$DAY, '%d-%b')

# new df with as.Date column
newdf <- cbind(dates, df)

# new column is class "Date"
class(newdf$dates)

# want date in format dd-mmm but converting it changes to class(character)
dates_changed <- format(dates, "%d-%b")
class(dates_changed)
```

I've managed to convert the original dd-mmm format to yyyy-mm-dd format, but this isn't desired as years are in the columns. I might just end up keeping this format as it enables me to graph in the dates in order but it doesn't seem ideal.

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: try with `as.Date(paste0(df$DAY, "-2019"), "%d-%b-%Y")` as date needs year as well

Comment: Thanks akrun, this is a little better than my solution and sort of answers my original question. Seems that i need to somehow merge the year column name with the month/day row name.